# How does the specific recursive method work in Java? Exercise 6.6 from Think Java book

Tags: java, recursion

everybody. Need your help. Stuck on the exercise 6.6 from "Think Java" by Downey and Mayfield:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(prod(1, 4));
}
public static int prod(int m, int n) {
    if (m == n) {
       return n;
    } else {
       int recurse = prod(m, n - 1);
       int result = n * recurse;
       return result;
    }
}
```

**What does exactly *prod* does?** Can you please explain?

I understand that it takes 1 and 4 as arguments and compares at first them between each other. Then since 1 doesn't equal 4 it goes to *else* and again goes to *prod* method, this time with arguments 1 and 3. And so on.

I ran the code in the editor with intermediate recurse outputs to see what happens inside *prod*. Got *recurse = 1, recurse = 2, recurse = 6* consequently. But how are they produced?

Comment: I often feel that people try to treat recursion as some concept different from just invoking a method; it just so happens that method has the same name as the current one. Would you understand if you made copies of the method so that `prod` invoked `prod1`, `prod1` invokes `prod2` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
prod(1, 4)
```

calls

```
prod(1, 3)
```

which calls

```
prod(1, 2)
```

which calls

```
prod(1, 1)
```

which returns 1

then

```
prod(1, 2) returns n * recurse, which is 2 * 1 = 2
```

then

```
prod(1, 3) returns n * recurse, which is 3 * 2 = 6
```

then

```
prod(1, 4) returns n * recurse, which is 4 * 6 = 24
```